# Subset boxplot by date

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to make a boxplot based on timeseries with 10-days data categories

```
set.seed(100)
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "days")
x <- as.integer(abs(rnorm(365))*1000)
df <- data.frame(date, x)

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(y=x,
                       x=reorder(format(df$date,'10 days'),df$date),
                       fill=format(df$date,'%Y'), 
                       group=cut(df$date, "10 days"))) +
      xlab('10 Dyas') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Year")) +
      theme_bw()
```

But I got result like this

[image]

I don't know why I got NA here and the x label does not display axis of date like 1-10 Jan, 11-20 Jan, etc

Is there something wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try to help you work out the problem. I think it would be easy to work out the problem if you generate variables needed before `ggplot`:

```
set.seed(100)
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "days")
x <- as.integer(abs(rnorm(365))*1000)
df <- data.frame(date, x)
library(tidyverse)

df1<-df %>% 
  mutate(
      x1=reorder(format(date,'10 days'),date),
      fill=format(date,'%Y'), 
      group=cut(date, "10 days")
 )

df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = x, x= date, fill=fill, group= group))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

Then if you check your data `df1`, you will find that when `group == 2013-12-27`, `fill` has two values: `2013` and `2014`. That's why you got a `NA` group in addition to `2013` and `2014`. Solution depends on how you want to assign the value to this group, or alternative way to group. A silly quick fix is

```
df1$fill = ifelse(as.character(df1$group) == "2013-12-27", "2013", df1$fill)
```

You can also check your `x` axis generated by `x = reorder(format(df$date,'10 days'), df$date)` (I used x1) is only one value: `10 days`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_x_date`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=x,
                   x=date,
                   fill=format(date,'%Y'))) +  
   xlab('Monthly data') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Year")) +
   theme_bw() + 
   scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month') + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

I chose 1 month as break interval for better visibility but you can use `"10 days"` if you want.

Comment: I want to display boxplot based on 10 days data

Comment: When I rerun with `ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=x,
                   x=reorder(format(df$date,'10 days'),df$date),
                   fill=format(date,'%Y'))) +  
  xlab('10 days') + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Year")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = '10 days') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`

I got error

Comment: @ExHunter Try `ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y=x,
                   x=date,
                   group = cut(date, '10 days'))) + 
   guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Year")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month') + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))`. Although, I don't understand what you are trying to do with `format(df$date,'10 days')`.